# Gmail filter which removes a label

Tags: gmail-filters

I've actually 2 questions.

**The first one**, simpler: is it still possible to create filter manually with a Boolean string or do we have to use the filter tool (the form it comes out when you create or modify a filter)?

**Second one:** I've a filter which puts all messages coming from `work@mywork.com` in a "work" folder. Let's call it "WORKFILTER". Great, it works!

I want to put some of them in a subfolder "work/subfolder1" but **not** to give them the "work" label (only "work/subfolder" label).

Is it possible to do that *only* with a second filter (let's call that "SUBFOLDERFILTER") in which I archive the message coming from `subfolder@address.com` with the label "work/subfolder1" but NOT with  "work" label?

something like:

```
from:(subfolder@address.com) label:"work/subfolder1" AND NOT(label:"work")
```

Or do I have to modify the "WORKFILTER" specifying to label with "work" all the messages coming from "work@mywork.com" *but not* the ones coming from "subfolder@address.com"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First part:** yes you can start from the search box and then when you see the results use More/Create Filter.

**Second Part:** The problem is that that if you include the phrase "label" in the search string and try to make the filer you will get the forllowing warning.

> Filter searches containing "label:",  "in:", "is:", or stars criteria (i.e. "has:yellow-star") are not recommended as they will never match incoming mail.
>
> Do you still wish to continue to the next step?**

I have seen nothing that allows you to order the filters, or tell it to stop processing other filters if this one is applied. These types of rules/actions are typically seen in other email systems. Remember the strength of the labels is the ability to file a conversation under multiple labels, so telling it to ignore other rules isn't an action that is needed very often.

The two filter method will work, If it comes from address 1 give it one label. If it comes from the second address then give it label 2. You can even use the not to make sure that only those from address 1 go to label 1.